# How to retrieve the data from the website, if the google API is not providing the info? I want full description instead of one line

Tags: python, api, google-api

I have zero knowledge on coding. but I want to gather all the info (title, description, image, price) using UPC (universal product code). I m getting all the info like title, description, price,. But the problem is I m not getting the full description, currently I am getting only one line. I don't want to ask the website provide the API, because there are wide range of UPCs i.e. products. How I do get the description data from the website without using API. give me alternative routes.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSx8vtNSR6fATg1h7c34jfD_a1Zq_ep_4LUHHdiHhWQTL9JyBsQbNO709B4837tYlO3-nWQLftnq0nc/pubhtml

Code:

```
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd

API_KEY = 'API_KEY'
SEARCH_ENGINE_ID = '77fdc4de42ee54ae3'

upc_number = '8411061784273'

url = f'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=API_KEY&cx=77fdc4de43ee54ae3&q=8411061784273'

response = requests.get(url).json()

results = []
for item in response['items']:
    title = item['title']
    description = item['snippet']
    link = item['link']
    price = "N/A"
    if 'pagemap' in item and 'offer' in item['pagemap']:
        for price_data in item['pagemap']['offer']:
            if 'price' in price_data:
                price = price_data['price']
                break
    results.append({'Title': title, 'Description': description, 'Link': link, 'Price': price})

df = pd.DataFrame(results)
df.to_excel('product_data.xlsx', index=False)
```

Expecting
full line description
Launch year: 2014. Top notes: Grapefruit, Bergamot, Pineapple, Melon, Green apple. Heart notes: Neroli, Jasmine, Cardamom, Marine accord. Base notes: Cedarwood, Vetiver, Amber, Suede, White musk. Design house: Antonio Banderas. Scent name: King Of Seduction. Gender: Mens. Category: Perfume. SubType: EDT Spray. Size: 3.4 oz. Barcode: 8411061784273. Antonio Banderas Men's King Of Seduction EDT Spray 3.4 oz Fragrances 8411061784273.

This item is only valid for shipment in the Contiguous United States.

Comment: Please tell me that’s not your actual API key

Comment: If the API key you provided in your question is real, please change it as soon as possible.

Comment: @Selcuk - yes its from Chatgpt. Why not use that variable?

Comment: @InSync I changed. do you know the solution, I got a solution which is called RPA.

Comment: @HiPeople - its not the actual api key anymore.

Comment: I didn't say "don't use it". I said "you are not using it". This code doesn't make much sense. Don't trust chatGPT for such tasks.